# How to split table by row in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

Simple question: I have a table that needs to be split into 2 tables via a row split and not the column split. How can I achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: By what criteria to you want to split by, can you show an example of the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duplicate the table, then delete the columns that you do not need from each of the copies.

To duplicate the table, open `Power Query Editor` by clicking on `Edit Queries`, right click your table and select `Duplicate`:

[image]

Then in each of the copies, right click on the header of the columns that you don't want, and select `Remove`. Alternatively, you can select the columns that you want to keep, and select `Remove other columns`.

[image]